# How can I use the chain operator do calculation with itself in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function, where x is between 0 and 1:

[image]

How can I use the chain operator `%>%` from `dplyr` package to do it?

I tried the following:

```
x = 0.5
y <- (x-1)^2 %>% 1-. %>% sqrt()
```

But this is wrong! How can I find a way with the chain operator do calculation with itself? I made here just a small example. I have a long equation and want to made the code readable with chain operator.

Comment: Use the chain operator from magrittr. `(x-1)^2 %>% { sqrt(1-.) }` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html

Comment: @Frank , Thanks!  The {} is the solution!

Comment: `computeY <- function(x) { sqrt(1-(x-1)^2)) }`

Comment: Or what about:  `x %>% "-"(1) %>% "^"(2) %>% "-"(.) %>% "+"(1) %>% sqrt`? In other words, I don't think pipes are really going to make your more complex example more readable.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks! You are right, the pipe operator can make complex example more worse! I should use the suggestion from Dirk Eddelbuettel. This is more clear and readable!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  I always try to write code in a different way, but this time, the basic methods is the best! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @xirururu Trust me when I say not only this time ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer as the OP appears to agree (and removing a spurious `)` in the process):

```
computeY <- function(x) { sqrt(1-(x-1)^2) }
```

which at the prompt works as well:

```
R> computeY <- function(x) { sqrt(1-(x-1)^2) }
R> sapply((1:5)/10, computeY)
[1] 0.435890 0.600000 0.714143 0.800000 0.866025
R>
```

*Disclaimer: No pipes were hurt in the production of this answer.*

Comment: `computeY((1:5)/10)` works in this case (instead of `sapply`).